# What conserved quantities are in 1D free quantum particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

From Laundau & Lifshitz "Quantum Mechanics":

> If there are two conserved physical quantities $f$ and $g$ whose operators do not commute, then the energy levels of the system are in general degenerate.

Let's consider a 1D free particle. Its wavefunction would be

$$\left<x\middle|\psi\right>=e^{ikx}$$

For all $k>0$ it's twice-degenerate: $E(k)=E(-k)$. I know there are two conserved quantities here: energy and momentum (wavenumber). But their operators commute. But judging from the quote, there should exist another quantity, which would have operator, which doesn't commute with momentum or energy operator. What is this quantity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parity.

For a free particle, both momentum and parity are conserved, and they do not commute as $\Pi p=-p\Pi$. Thus the degeneracy.