# What conserved quantities does a one-dimensional non-symmetric lattice have?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, group-theory

When I [asked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73900/what-conserved-quantities-are-in-1d-free-quantum-particle) what leads to degeneracy of eigenstates of free particle, the answer was parity. But it appears that even if we consider a lattice with non-symmetric cell, so the potential looks as shown below, we still have Bloch's theorem, with which $E(k)=E(-k)$.

[image]

The potential is clearly not invariant under parity inversion, but the two-fold degeneracy is still there. So, there must be something more than just quasimomentum and, in some cases, parity, which lead to degeneracy.

A similar case is when we consider the potential, which has broken symmetry group of [$D_4$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_groups#dihedral_group_of_order_8), which, as I understand, after breaking has symmetry group [$C_4$](http://www.webqc.org/symmetrypointgroup-c4.html), isomorphic to the symmetry of the above 1D potential:

[image]

This $C_4$ group is abelian, but for some reason there're twice-degenerate states.

So, the question is: what is this extra symmetry which I'm missing here?

Comment: Why does Bloch's Theorem guarantee us that $E(k) = E(-k)$?

Comment: @BySymmetry well, it's not the Bloch's theorem itself which guarantees this. I mention it to say that there's a conserved quantity $k$. And $E(k)=E(-k)$ follows from the fact that the eigenfunction (in absense of magnetic field) can always be chosen to be real. Thus, if we take real part or complex conjugate of the Bloch wave, it still is a solution with the same eigenvalue. But complex conjugate here means switch $k\to-k$. Thus the eigenvalue is invariant in reflection of $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the symmetry you are looking for is probably time-reversal invariance. In other words, if your Hamiltonian is 
$$ H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x), $$
this is invariant under $p\to -p$, $x\to x$, irrespectively of the symmetries of $V(x)$. A representation of this transformation is given simply by complex conjugation, i.e. $\Theta \psi = \psi^{\ast}$. If $\psi$ is an eigenvector of $H$ with eigenvalue $E$, then so is $\psi^{\ast}$, which follows from $\Theta H \Theta^{-1} = H$. If your lattice has periodic boundary conditions, then both left- and right-moving states (with $\pm k$) are independent (orthogonal) solutions of the Schroedinger equation with energy $E(k)$.